# How to change author base without front

Tags: permalinks, url-rewriting

I am currently using this code:

```
function change_author_permalinks() {
    global $wp_rewrite;
    $wp_rewrite->author_base = 'connect/member';
}
add_action('init','change_author_permalinks');
```

but my current `front` set on my blog is:

`share`

So the above generates a URL like so:

`http://example.com/share/connect/member/john-smith`

But I don't want `/share/` as part of this author URL. I cannot remove the `/share/` front as it is needed for other parts of the site.

How do I set the author URL to not use `front`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is the best solution I have come up with but I welcome better ways:

```
function change_author_permalinks() {
    global $wp_rewrite;
    $wp_rewrite->author_base = 'connect/member';
    $wp_rewrite->author_structure = "/" . $wp_rewrite->author_base . '/%author%';
    add_rewrite_rule('connect/member/([^/]+)/?$', 'index.php?author_name=$matches[1]', 'top');
}
add_action('init','change_author_permalinks');
```

Comment: A reminder to all to visit your Settings > Permalinks page after making this change to functions.php in order to refresh your site's permalinks. Before I had done that my author base was properly changed, but the link returned a 404. (WordPress still had the author page living at /front/authors/username.)